# When i use Activity in camel case it gives error but works fine in upper case spelled

Tags: android, android-activity, uppercase

Hy! Expets i have two activities 
1- MainActivity
2- Startup

I am starting my `MainActivity` activity through new intent after starting `Startup` activity using Thread. but when when i call new intent by passing `MainActivity` spelled in camel case and within inten-filter tag `<action android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"`  as shown below

```
Thread timer =new Thread(){
public void run(){
 try{
sleep(5000);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
Intent startUpIntent = new Intent("com.example.test.MainActivity");                         

startActivity(startUpIntent);
                    }
                }
            };
```

and here is AndroidMaifest.xml File code

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test.Startup"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.newboston.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

it gives error. 
But when I use code as

```
Intent startUpIntent = new Intent("com.example.test.MainActivity");
```

AndroidManifest.xml code

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

then it works fine  as i want.

I want to know reason to use Upper case spelled instead of camel case.???

Thanx...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be defining an [intent for a specific component](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29):

```
Intent startUpIntent = new Intent(Startup.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Then you don't need to bother with an `<intent-filter>` for `MainActivity` in your manifest.

Comment: Thanx @Ted Hopp.  but can u tell me reason what is the problem with my method.

Comment: @LASIAF - Frankly, I don't see the difference between the code you say "gives error" and the code you say works. You say that "it gives error"; what error?

Comment: it does not start activity with camel case spelled.

Comment: @LASIAF - Is there anything in the logcat output? Also, can you point out the difference between the code that doesn't work and the code that does? They look identical to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of action constants defined in the `Intent` class. Some of them are:

```
ACTION_MAIN: Start up as the initial activity of a task, with no data input and no returned output. 

ACTION_CALL: Initiate a phone call. 

ACTION_EDIT: Display data for the user to edit.
```

To use `ACTION MAIN` in your manifest, you will replace the `ACTION_` part with `android.intent.action.`. Since they are constants defined in a class you are using, they need to be used as defined.

For example, the following two declarations are not the same. They define and instantiate two different variables:

```
int myVariable = 1;
int MYVARIABLE = 1;
```

So, you cannot write:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

as

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.main" />
```

or anything other that the former.

From the android developers resource page on `<action>`:

> To assign one of [standard actions defined in the Intent class] to
>   this attribute, prepend "android.intent.action." to the string that
>   follows ACTION_. For example, for ACTION_MAIN, use
>   "android.intent.action.MAIN" and for ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, use
>   "android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH".

To read up more on this:

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[action](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html)